# Where does the kernel ring buffer sit relative to rsyslog?

Tags: logs, syslog, dmesg

Is `rsyslog` just an abstraction layer on top of the kernel ring buffer? Or is the kernel ring buffer its own entity and `rsyslog`s interaction is like that of any other "application"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although various pieces of documentation (including `man dmesg`) refer to it as "the kernel ring buffer", it might be better to refer to it as the kernel log buffer, since "ring buffer" is a generic term and I believe the kernel also uses ring buffers for various completely unrelated things.  The "printk buffer" is also appropriate, after the kernel space function used to write to it.

Anyway, it resides in kernel space and a read interface is provided via `/proc/kmsg` and a read-write interface via `/dev/kmsg`.  So if as root you go:

```
echo "Hello Kernel!" > /dev/ksmg
```

You'll see it if you then `cat /dev/ksmg` (you probably won't see this turning up in any logs, however -- see Matthew Phipps' comment below for a possible reason).  This is raw output and does not look exactly like the stuff you see from `dmesg` or in your log files. There is a little [bit of documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/dev-kmsg) about this provided with the kernel source. Reading from `/proc/kmsg` (not the same as `/dev/ksmg`) is recommended against if (r)syslog is running.

Rsyslog is one of a number of[syslog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog) implementations commonly used on linux.  These are userland applications that source kernel messages from `/proc/ksmg` and messages from other userland processes via a socket, `/dev/log`.

Comment: I'd point out that rsyslog has $KLogPermitNonKernelFacility off by default, which is why non-kernel messages from /proc/kmsg will be ignored by rsyslog unless you turn that option on. This can actually get really confusing, since Upstart, for example, logs to /proc/kmsg with a non-kernel facility.